# C# Writing Directory

Tags: c#

I seem to can't get it to write a text to the text file or ini file. It keeps writing and pasting it in my source folder in Visual Studio. So I run it, and it asks if i want to save it to the directory, but it keeps pasting it to the wrong file, and it won't write to the right, file as you can see below. I keep and trying to fix it, but nothing will work.

```
            Console.Title = "Night Premium";

            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            Console.WriteLine("----------------Update-Log-----------------");
            Console.WriteLine("-                                         -");
            Console.WriteLine("- 1. New premium ranks                    -");
            Console.WriteLine("-                                         -");
            Console.WriteLine("-                                         -");
            Console.WriteLine("-                                         -");
            Console.WriteLine("-                                         -");
            Console.WriteLine("-                                         -");
            Console.WriteLine("-                                         -");
            Console.WriteLine("-                                         -");
            Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------");

            Console.WriteLine("\n");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Night premium! Please sign in");
            Console.WriteLine("\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Password: ");
            if (Console.ReadLine() == Data)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n");
                Console.WriteLine("Checking passwords...");
                Console.WriteLine("Are we allowed to create a directory file, for Night premium in C:/Night_Premium { Y|N }");
                Console.WriteLine("\n");
                if (Console.ReadLine() == "Y")
                {
                     Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Night_Premium");
                     Console.WriteLine("Created Directory....");
                     Console.WriteLine("\n");
                     Thread.Sleep(3000);
                    if (!File.Exists(@"C:\Night_Premium\Whitelist.txt"))
                    {
                        File.Create(@"C:\Night_Premium\Whitelist.txt");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Writing to whitelist.txt");
                        Console.WriteLine("\n");
                        Thread.Sleep(3000); ;
                        {
                            File.WriteAllText(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\Settings.ini", "TopMost = true");
                            Console.WriteLine();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean this line `File.WriteAllText(...)`? Well, it depends what the current directory is.Or do you mean whitelist.txt? You never write to it,

Comment: I am confused. Your program displays the message "Writing to whitelist.txt" but the code immediately afterward writes to a file named Settings.ini. Is this intentional?

Comment: Please read [MCVE] guidance on posting code - 90% of code posted has nothing to do with the question (which after creating true minimal sample will become "Why Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() does not change when I create new directory")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to write to the newly created directory. So you need a variable to set the target depending on the decision of the user.

So I would use an additional variable to store the current directory:

```
var targetname = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\Settings.ini;
```

If the user the creation of the directory overwrite it:

```
var targetname = @"C:\Night_Premium\Whitelist.txt"
```

Change also your WriteAllText Code to use this variable:

```
File.WriteAllText(targetname, "TopMost = true");
```

=============================================

Alternate:

Iff you want only to write to the "Night Premium" directory you could sure simply use this:

```
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Night_Premium\Settings.ini", "TopMost = true");
```

Comment: The first backslash in your last code section is wrong

Answer (score 0):

directory.getcurrentdirectory will get the folder where you are executing code. Use a variable or hardcode the path there instead to your desired folder.